# Serverless logs on AWS CloudWatch dont work

Tags: nestjs, serverless, serverless-framework

I'm trying to get logs of a production Serverless deployment (nestjs) on AWS CloudWatch. I tried setting cloudwatchLog on the function as well as the logs block on the api level to no avail. I only see the general startup logs appear and then empty logs (console.log is supposed to write to the logs but it doesn't). How this can be fixed?

```
2023-08-03T09:39:10.945+02:00   INIT_START Runtime Version: nodejs:16.v16 Runtime Version ARN: arn:aws:lambda:eu-west-2::runtime:c1983f4e9ce3930d3093fa38128e12edac2324f4fe99adfb8e0d5fb6b6afadbc

2023-08-03T09:39:34.476+02:00   START RequestId: 41d79246-7bd6-48bf-8eac-f4ab5f65e9c1 Version: $LATEST

2023-08-03T09:39:34.945+02:00   [32m[Nest] 8 - [39m08/03/2023, 7:39:34 AM [32m LOG[39m [38;5;3m[NestFactory] [39m[32mStarting Nest application...[39m

controllers mapped etc...

2023-08-03T09:39:35.607+02:00   [32m[Nest] 8 - [39m08/03/2023, 7:39:35 AM [32m LOG[39m [38;5;3m[NestApplication] [39m[32mNest application successfully started[39m[38;5;3m +22ms[39m

2023-08-03T09:39:35.632+02:00   END RequestId: 41d79246-7bd6-48bf-8eac-f4ab5f65e9c1

2023-08-03T09:39:35.632+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 41d79246-7bd6-48bf-8eac-f4ab5f65e9c1 Duration: 1155.60 ms Billed Duration: 1156 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 192 MB Init Duration: 2183.01 ms

2023-08-03T09:39:37.100+02:00   START RequestId: 8de822b4-a562-46cd-8f45-68d58df9bcc6 Version: $LATEST

2023-08-03T09:39:37.106+02:00   END RequestId: 8de822b4-a562-46cd-8f45-68d58df9bcc6

2023-08-03T09:39:37.106+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 8de822b4-a562-46cd-8f45-68d58df9bcc6 Duration: 5.27 ms Billed Duration: 6 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 193 MB

2023-08-03T09:39:39.005+02:00   START RequestId: 4d6c8e4f-b840-4200-a1e4-b7a087f36cad Version: $LATEST

2023-08-03T09:39:39.010+02:00   END RequestId: 4d6c8e4f-b840-4200-a1e4-b7a087f36cad

2023-08-03T09:39:39.010+02:00   REPORT RequestId: 4d6c8e4f-b840-4200-a1e4-b7a087f36cad Duration: 5.00 ms Billed Duration: 5 ms Memory Size: 1024 MB Max Memory Used: 193 MB

2023-08-03T09:44:02.337+02:00   START RequestId: c5028e01-8a5f-4bc5-97dc-d99231b4bee5 Version: $LATEST

2023-08-03T09:44:02.357+02:00   END RequestId: c5028e01-8a5f-4bc5-97dc-d99231b4bee5
```

I created the cloudwatch log group and set the cloudwatchLog line to it, but that log group is completely empty so I'm using the default `aws/lambda/x` log group.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely the console.log() statements are not being called. I sit part of a function which is probably not reached? Maybe, put the first line as console.log('hello') and see if it is outputted.

Iam role and internet or endpoint settings are correct since it's writing some messages are to cloudwatch.